# Area of $3$ triangles on the sides of a triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles

A point inside a triangle creates $3$ triangles with total area = the outer triangle area.

Will it be the same if the point is outside the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if you use signed area.